# Question about Relation of asymptotic equality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If Xn~Yn, then limit of xn/yn as n goes to infinity is 1.

I do not understand why this is reflexive.

One of my homework question is like prove if xn~yn, then yn~xn.

let xn= n^2  and yn=n then reflexive is not true...

Comment: I mean symmetric

Comment: OMG stupid example sorry never mind

Comment: n^2/n is not convergent to 1

Comment: if $x_n = n^2$ and $y_n = n$, then $x_n / y_n \not= 1$ as $n \to \infty$